# ValueError Still Present with Except Statement

Tags: python, except

I am trying to create a program for that explores the collatz sequence.  It works until I try to add `try` and `except` statements to ensure the user enters a number and not text.  Below is the code:

```
def collatz(number):
    try:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print(number // 2)
            return number // 2
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            result = 3 * number + 1
            print(result)
            return result
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a number')

print('Enter a number')
n = int(input())

while n != 1:
    n = collatz(int(n))
```

I can run it with no problems if I enter numbers.  However, when I enter the word "puppy" I encounter this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kredeker/Desktop/python/collatz2.py", line 14, in <module>
    n = int(input())
```

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'puppy'
```

I thought I was accounting for the `ValueError` with this:

```
except ValueError:
    print('That is not a number')
```

Comment: The exception handling is done in the function. `n = int(input())` is outside the function. You can drop the int call `n = input()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error at `n = int(input())`!

So try doing

```
try:
  n = int(input())
except ValueError:
  print('That is not a number')
```

The full code (so that you don't get an error with 'n'):

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = 3 * number + 1
        print(result)
        return result

print('Enter a number')

try:
  n = int(input())
  while n != 1:
    n = collatz(n)
except ValueError:
  print('That is not a number')
```

Comment: None of the code in the `collatz()` function will throw a `ValueError` exception, there is no need to keep the `try....except` in that function.

Comment: You have a redundant call to `int()` still: `n = collatz(n)` will do.

Answer (score 2):

The `try...except` applies to only code that is run between these words, including function calls. As the traceback shows, your exception occurs on the line 14:

```
n = int(input())  # <---
```

which is caused by the string that you entered (`puppy`) not being interpretable as an integer in base 10.

You need to wrap this within a `try` ... `except`; but a better option would be to adopt - and adapt - the functions from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/918959).